# How do I get the "biggest" path?

Tags: python

I need to write some Python code to get the latest version of Android from a path.  For example:

```
$ ls -l android_tools/sdk/platforms/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 5 deqing deqing 4096 Mar 21 11:42 android-18
drwxrwxr-x 5 deqing deqing 4096 Mar 21 11:42 android-19
$
```

In this case I'd like to have `android_tools/sdk/platforms/android-19`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`max` function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#max) can take a `key=myfunc` parameter to specify a function that will return a comparison value. So you could do something like:

```
import os, re
dirname = 'android_tools/sdk/platforms'
files = os.listdir(my_dir)
def mykeyfunc(fname):
    digits = re.search(r'\d+$', fname).group()
    return int(digits)
print max(files, mykeyfunc)
```

Adjust that regular expression as needed for the actual files you're dealing with, and that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks. Can I pass regular expression into `mykeyfunc`? As sometimes I need to match like `18.0.0.0` and `19.0.0.0`, maybe I need '\d+.*$' in that case.

Comment: @Deqing - The `key=` parameter requires a function that takes one parameter. My suggestion would be to write a single key function that handles all the numeric cases you're expecting to encounter (which might use a regex, or might use other parsing techniques -- regular expressions aren't suited for every problem). But if you really want to pass in a regex as a parameter, try doing `def mykeyfunc(myre, fname)` then using it with `max(key=functools.partial(mykeyfunc, re_to_use))`. See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) for how to use `functools.partial`.